# Does the product of three Gaussian random matrices converge in distribution to a Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

1. Suppose we have vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^r$ with and matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ where all entries of $u,v,W$ are iid $N(0,1)$. Does the following hold?
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{r} u^TWv \overset{d}\rightarrow N(0,1) \hspace{5mm}\text{as } r \rightarrow \infty
   \end{equation}
2. Extension: Suppose we have matrices $U,V \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$ and $W \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ where all entries of $U,V,W$ are iid $N(0,1)$. Does the following hold?
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{r} U^TWV \overset{d}\rightarrow N(0,I) \hspace{5mm}\text{as } r \rightarrow \infty
   \end{equation}

Through numerical experiments I am convinced that these claims are true, but I'm having difficulty proving even 1. Expressing the LHS as a sum of $r^2$ terms, dependencies are introduced by the elements of $u,v$. Hence I was trying to use a version of the Central Limit Theorem for dependent variables, but without much success. Note that each entry of the LHS in 2 is the LHS in 1. Hence the extension 2, would be a matter of checking whether the entries of the LHS converge jointly to a Gaussian.

I would be grateful if someone could give a proof, or give pointers to where this problem is tackled.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I have reevaluated my answer.

We can restate your problem as a stochastic problem such that

$ X_r = \rho X_{r-1} + \epsilon_r $

with $ \epsilon_r = \frac{1}{r}\left(u_r W_{rr} v_r + \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} u_i W_{ir} v_r + u_r W_{ri} v_i \right) $ and $ \rho = \frac{r - 1}{r} $

this can be interpreted as summing the values from the first row and column to the last row and column iteratively.

Since $ |\rho| < 1 $, we can see that the process is strictly stationary. Based on this observation, the CLT for strictly convergent processes can be used to proof (1).

However, the extension statement does not make sense to me, since a given vector $ x $ can be $ x \sim N(0,I) $ but a matrix cannot.

Comment: Yes I am aware that for fixed $r$ that the LHS is not Gaussian. However I'm taking the limit as $r \rightarrow \infty$, and doing a normality test I'm seeing results that look like Gaussians. Note that for the central limit theorem for example, the sample means in consideration are not Gaussian, but they converge in distribution to a Gaussian in the limit of infinite samples. I'm trying to do something similar here.

Comment: Sorry I missed the point of your question. I have restated my answer, however it is not a complete proof, but a path to find it.

Comment: OK so are you claiming this is a strictly stationary process since it is an Autoregressive model of order 1 (AR(1)) with $\rho < 1$? But then one must show that the $\epsilon_r$ are white noise, i.e. that they are independent. This is not the case - we can easily verify that $cov(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)>0$. Also regarding the extension, when I say $M \sim N(0,I)$ for a matrix $M$, I mean that its entries are iid $N(0,1)$. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I actually removed that from my answer, but indeed $ \forall i, j: Cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j) > 0 $ so you cannot say it is a AR(1). I personally don't know how to finish this proof since my knowledge on this kind of problem is limited to the AR(1) case. However, due to the similarity to it, you can probably search for necessary/sufficient conditions for the CLT when $ \epsilon_k $ are correlated and your problem might satisfy them.